# How to know if a function will be called for the last time

Tags: c

I'm working on a self-made malloc(), realloc() and free() for a school project.

I would like to know if there is a way for my function free() to know if it's his last call in the program.

Edit : I don't have main() under control, it's for a library.

I would like to use sbrk() to free just one time at the end, because for now i'm calling it after all free() and it's not optimised.

(I deleted the piece of code because i don't want to be strike by my school)

Seems that it's not possible.. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that knowledge?

Comment: so given `free(); free();` you want the second `free()` to behave differently?

Comment: Sounds equivalent to the Halting Problem.

Comment: Do you have function `main` under your control, or are you developing a library?

Comment: As @Fildor said, you should rather specify why you'd want to do something like this. Likely you're approaching your problem from a wrong angle.

Comment: It's a school projet, i would like to use sbrk() to free just one time at the end, because for now i'm calling it after all free()

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking, or why you'd need to know that. Do you mean that if you have `free(); if(rand()%2) free();` the first `free()` should somehow know if the second one will be called or not?

Comment: @WilliamChoukroun Why bother freeing anything at the end?

Comment: *I would like to use sbrk() to free just one time at the end, because for now i'm calling it after all free()* How can you know that the last call to `free()` has been done?  @jjj posted an example of code where you can never know what the last call to `free()` might be.  *it's not optimised*  So what?  [Premature optimization is the root of all evil.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_(1974))

Comment: "free(); if(rand()%2) free();" ahah
I'm more thinking about knowing the last potential call in the program, maybe the compilater know it

Comment: @WilliamChoukroun *maybe the compiler know it* How can the compiler know which call in `free(); if(rand()%2) free();` will be the last one?  There's no way to know - ever.

Comment: Knowing the "last potential call" is practically worthless – either the cleanup code will sometimes not be called, which leads to bugs that are hard to debug, or if it doesn't matter if the cleanup code is sometimes not called, why include it at all?

Comment: @JJJ Even worse, what if the "last call" isn't? For example, an `exit()` handler registered with `atexit()` calls `free()` after the supposed-to-be "last" call.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is, in general, no way to know whether a function is being called for the last time in a program execution.

A program could be designed to convey this knowledge, by passing an argument indicating it. You would have to build this into all functions in the call chain. Even so, it may cause some code to be awkward, as the last iterations of some loops may need special treatment.

Generally, it is preferable to call separate clean-up code at suitable times rather than trying to incorporate it automatically into routine operations in the way you seem to be attempting.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot.

Example :

- A GUI will call your function every time the user clicks "ok".
- There is no way for the program to known if the user will click again or switch-off the computer after a click.

A little joke:
The only possiblity for you, to achieve what you want, is have your function free() abort the whole program, so that you are sure it will not be called again.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, as other answers have stated.

The closest thing you can do is register an `atexit` handler to perform whatever cleanup you want to do:

```
static int init = 0;

void cleanup()
{
    // last call to sbrk to clean up
}

void *my_malloc(size_t size)
{
    if (!init) {
        init = 1;
        atexit(cleanup);
    }
    ...
}
```